# What is A' where A is a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, random-matrices

I'm reading MIT OpenCourseWare on Random Matrices, and am confused by some notation...

It says that one can construct a Wigner matrix from a random $N\times N$ matrix $G$ using:
\begin{equation}
W = \frac{G+G'}{\sqrt{2N}}
\end{equation}
What is G' here?

Comment: Ah okay! Yes thanks for that

Comment: Note that $G'$ being the transpose means that $W$ is manifestly symmetric. (If $G$ were a complex matrix, one would likely choose the Hermitian conjugate $G^\dagger$ instead so that $W$ would be Hermitian.)